# Как парсить файл, не разделенный на строки

Tags: парсер, любой-язык

Файл имеет такую структуру:

```
{date}\t{title}\t{message}\n
```

Проблема в том, что {message} иногда содержит и табуляцию (\t) и переносы (\n)

**Пример:**

```
30.01.2017    Первое сообщение    Текст первого сообщения, не содержащий табуляции или переноса строки
30.01.2017    Второе сообщение    Текст второго сообщения с    табуляцией
30.01.2017    Третье сообщение    Текст третьего сообщения
с переносом строки
и    табуляцией
```

Как распарсить файл на строки правильно?

Comment: прикрепи пример

Comment: в тексте всегда имеется  (\t) или (\n) или и то и другое ?

Comment: Нужно уточнить вопрос, на каком языке программирования писать код? На самом деле это можно сделать на десяти разных языках программирования (к примеру это вполне реализуемо на `PHP`, `JAVA` и `python`).

Comment: @fonjeekay решение подойдет на любом

Comment: @norbornen добавил пример

Comment: Ну так и ищите в начале строки токен, соответствующий по своему формату данным даты. Если таковой не найден - присоединяйте строку к текущей записи, а если найден - сбрасывайте текущую запись и начинайте парсинг новой.

Comment: @Akina текст вполне может содержать дату. Хотя, паттерн \n{date}\t впринципе можно принять за начало новой строки, ага

Comment: @сергейтамбовцев ага

Comment: Если текст может содержать дату, и деление текста на строки таково, что дата оказалась в начале строки, то я не вижу способа на приведённом описании определить, является дата значимым токеном или частичным содержимым токена. Ну разве что может помочь дополнительная попытка обнаружить в той же строке 2 табуляции. причём первую сразу после даты... либо проверка покажет, что выделяемый токен даты конфликтует с логикой смыслового содержания информации.

Comment: @сергейтамбовцев Если решение подойдет на любом, то нужно это описать в вашем вопросе, иначе мой пример с `php` заминусуют.

Comment: В общем случае эту задачу решить нельзя.

Comment: По хорошему, вам нужно удалить этот лог, и модифицировать логгер, чтобы корректно сериализовал сообщение.

Comment: когда то я решал подобную задачу. Суть была такая - пробежался по массиву и пометил строки, которые начинаются с даты. потом разделил на куски, так как позиции в тексте я знал. Дальше, рассматривал каждый кусок и смотрел, а может это часть предыдущего и конкатенировал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разделяйте файл на части по `^{date}\t{title}\t` шаблону:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import re
from pathlib import Path

text = Path('messages.txt').read_text()

date_re = r'\d\d\.\d\d\.\d{4}'
title_re = r'[^\t]+' # no tab in the title
parts = re.split(f'^({date_re})\t({title_re})\t', text, flags=re.M)[1:]

print(*parts, sep=' | ')
```

Вывод (сокращённый) для примера в вопросе:

```py
30.01.2017 | Первое сообщение | ...
 | 30.01.2017 | Второе сообщение | ...
 | 30.01.2017 | Третье сообщение | ...
```

Или более строго, можно проверить, что все даты разрешённые и положить каждое сообщение в свой объект с именованными атрибутами:

```py
from collections import namedtuple
from datetime import datetime

Message = namedtuple('Message', 'date title message')

triples = (parts[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(parts), 3))
messages = [Message(datetime.strptime(datestr, '%d.%m.%Y').date(), title, text)
            for datestr, title, text in triples]
print(*messages, sep='\n')
```

#### Результат

```py
Message(date=datetime.date(2017, 1, 30), title='Первое сообщение', message='Текст первого сообщения, не содержащий табуляции или переноса строки\n')
Message(date=datetime.date(2017, 1, 30), title='Второе сообщение', message='Текст второго сообщения с\tтабуляцией\n')
Message(date=datetime.date(2017, 1, 30), title='Третье сообщение', message='Текст третьего сообщения\nс переносом строки\nи\tтабуляцией\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

Обязательное условие для моего примера - отсутсвие табуляций в title и четкий формат даты.

Если вдруг в сообщении появится \n(дата)\t(текст)\t, все сломается

```php
$data = "\n".file_get_contents('messages.txt');

$lines = preg_split("/\n(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4})\t([^\t]+)\t/isu", $data, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

print_r($lines);
exit();

$messagesArray = [];
for ($i = 1; $i < count($lines); $i+=3) {
    $messagesArray[] = [
        'date' => $lines[$i],
        'title' => $lines[$i+1],
        'message' => $lines[$i+2],
    ];
}

print_r($messagesArray);

/**
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 30.01.2017
            [title] => Первое сообщение
            [message] => Текст первого сообщения, не содержащий табуляции или переноса строки

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 30.01.2017
            [title] => Второе сообщение
            [message] => Текст второго сообщения с      табуляцией

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [date] => 30.01.2017
            [title] => Третье сообщение
            [message] => Текст третьего сообщения
с переносом строки
и       табуляцией
        )

)

*/
```

Вообще я бы рекомендовал записывать в лог сериализованный массив, например JSON. Таким образом лог будет проще разобрать.

Для примера сделал такую запись:

```
30.01.2017  Второе сообщение    Текст второго сообщения с   табуляцией  
11.01.2016  test    test
test
```

Получил, как и ожидалось вот такой результат:

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [date] => 30.01.2017
        [title] => Второе сообщение
        [message] => Текст второго сообщения с      табуляцией
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [date] => 11.01.2016
        [title] => test
        [message] => test
test

    )
```

Но эту проблему никак не решить без изменения формата лога

Comment: Попрошу минусующих аргументировать свою позицию. Пока что я единственный, кто предложил вариант, который реально работает на приведенном примере от автора